# Group by mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I've a table like this in my db

```
 ID    PRODUCT     PRICE    QUANTITY    DATA           TOTAL
 1     ICECREAM    2        1           2015-10-05     2
 2     CHIPS       1        2           2015-10-05     2
 3     ICECREAM    2        2           2015-10-05     4

 4     ICECREAM    2        2           2015-10-06     4
 5     COFFEE      1        1           2015-10-06     1
```

how can i lunch a query to have an output like this:

```
Order data 2015-10-05
ICECREAM QUANTITY=3 TOTAL= 6
CHIPS QUANTITY=2 TOTAL=2


Order data 2015-10-05
ICECREAM QUANTITY=2 TOTAL= 2
COFFEE QUANTITY=1 TOTAL= 1
```

Comment: you don't have anything "in my phpmyadmin". phpmyadmin is a management interface. you have data in the mysql rdbms...

Comment: ok marc...sorry for the error...I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.DATA, p.PRODUCT, SUM(p.QUANTITY) as QtyTotal, SUM(p.TOTAL) as SumTotal
FROM PRODUCTS p
GROUP BY p.DATA, p.PRODUCT
```

You want to group by date and product, and sum the quantity and total.

**UPDATE:**
It appears that the OP actually has datetime, and not just date in the "data" column.  To get the totals by date, the datetime needs to be converted.

```
SELECT DATE(p.DATA), p.PRODUCT, SUM(p.QUANTITY) as QtyTotal, SUM(p.TOTAL) as SumTotal
FROM PRODUCTS p
GROUP BY DATE(p.DATA), p.PRODUCT
```

Comment: PERFECT YOU'RE a genius DEVLIN!

Comment: sorry devlin I use your code in this way
$sql="SELECT data, prodotto, SUM(quantita) as QtyTotal, SUM(totale_parziale) as SumTotal FROM barcode_consumazioni GROUP BY data, prodotto";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row["data"]."<br/>".$row["prodotto"]." ".$row["QtyTotal"]." ".$row["SumTotal"]."<br/>";

}
but the result was this

2015-10-05 14:12:10
Limonata 8 12.00

2015-10-05 14:14:57
coca cola 1 1.50

2015-10-05 14:14:57
Limonata 3 4.50

perhaps Ive done some mistake?

Comment: I'd like only one date and all order down it

Comment: so your "data" field is actually a datetime stamp and not just a date?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a query to convert datetime to date and group by date only

Comment: could you give me the php code with you sql code I must use to obtain the table as in my question? My result is always the same with 3 data-time as I said you in the comment before

Comment: the updated query I posted above should give you results by date, not datetime.

Comment: yes I know...but Id like an output with only a date..not 3 or 4 rows with data and product name, price, etc...

Comment: you should handle the display of your data separately from the query to get the data.

Comment: the problem is that I dont know how to do :-(

Comment: update your question to show what you've tried so far to display the results.

Comment: I'VE DONE!

here my solution

$prevValue = NULL;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$dates=$row["data"];
 if ($dates === $prevValue) {
echo $row["prodotto"]." ".$row["QtyTotal"]." ".$row["Sumtotale_parziale"]."<br/>";

 }
else
 {
echo $dates."<br/>".$row["prodotto"]." ".$row["QtyTotal"]." ".$row["Sumtotale_parziale"]."<br/>";

 }
 $prevValue = $dates;

}